# How to activate Facebook timeline for application test account

Tags: facebook, testing, facebook-timeline

After the introduction of new timeline at f8, I started to create a new app.
Today, on the application setting page, I created an application test user to test all the functionality such as 'add to timeline' plugin and publish_action permission.
But when I switch to the app test user, I don't see its timeline or a button to have timeline.
How can we have timeline for test users?

[RESOLVED]
Since the launch of timeline, visiting http://facebook.com/about/timeline works fine for test users, too.

Comment: I guess it is working only in the USA

Comment: This worked for me guys:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540957/how-do-i-activate-timeline-for-test-accounts-of-a-facebook-app#comment13638106_10540957

Comment: Since the launch of timeline I've been using the same way to have timeline installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bug assigned to address this problem at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/294393900595655

Comment: Thanks, I'll subscribe to the bug report. I really want to vote up your answer, but I'm 1 reputation short to vote.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create some custom action/object to unlock the timeline.