# How do I activate Timeline for Test Accounts of a Facebook App?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a web app that publishes actions to a users timeline.

With my test accounts it says that I cannot publish actions since the user isn't using Timeline.

I go to the Timeline page while logged in as that user and it's unavailable there.
I also add the developer app for the users and this doesn't open up the option.
I edit the profile settings and there is nothing there.
I view the profile and there is nothing there.
I've checked with test accounts that are over a year old.

`{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) User ############### is not allowed to create actions of custom action type because their Timeline is not activated",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}`

Comment: Can't you go to http://www.facebook.com/about/timeline and activate it there while being logged in as a testuser?

Comment: Nope. tried that. the option is not available for any of my 5 test users.

Comment: added the JSON code being returned upon error.

Comment: If they're newly created platform test users it takes a few minutes before that link appears

Comment: as mentioned above: "I've checked with test accounts that are over a year old."

Comment: Are they proper test accounts created via the API or the 'Roles' interface on the developer site?

Comment: Roles Interface on the developer site. I don't think the API existed at the time of writing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These accounts eventually transitioned to "Timeline" profiles. My guess is that I was too close to when they introduced Timeline that it delayed the process.